# How do I clone React component DOM nodes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component where I'm trying to render a Excel-like grid with a fixed header and fixed first column. The desired behavoir is:

- scroll left & right: 1st column stays in place while other columns scroll including the header row
- scroll up & down: all columns scroll up & down except header that stays fixed

Existing techniques that work for this clone the fixed header and column into another div that is overlaid the existing table - this allows the table to behave as usual and only the X & Y offsets of the fixed divs need to adjust. see example: http://www.disconova.com/open_source/files/freezepanes.htm

How do I structure this with React?

So far I have something like:

```
var Grid = React.createClass({
    renderRow: function (row, i) {
        return (<GridRow key={i} rowIdx={i} cols={row} />);
    },
    render: function () {
      return (
        <div className="grid-container" ref="container">

          <!-- this is where I *think* I need cloned divs --> 

          <div className="grid" ref="grid">
            <div className="grid-body">
              {this.props.rows.map(this.renderRow)}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
});
```

I was thinking that I would have a `<FixedRow />` and `<FixedColumn />` components where the above comment is, but I'm not sure how I go about getting the DOM nodes of the rows that need to be cloned. Th reason for cloning being they have to match in attributes, dimensions etc. Any ideas as to how to go about this?

Comment: Why not try something like an onScroll handler and set the position fixed when a certain section is being scrolled?

Comment: Yes thats the plan. Its not so much about the scrolling that is an issue but the initial construction of the copied elements. With React I could create an initial fixed column and header component but they wouldn't be the right size to match the row AFAIK this isn't known to React as its an attribute of the rendered DOM node (i.e. the thing I need to copy from)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the example when commenting